# How to use IN operator with AND operator in WHERE clause in SQL...?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am using this database query in my CodeIgniter model.

```
SELECT
                p.product_id,
                p.product_name,
                p.product_photo,
                p.size,
                p.price,
                p.status,
                p.product_image_path
            FROM
                products AS p
            LEFT JOIN
                product_category AS pc
            ON
                p.product_id = pc.product_id
            LEFT JOIN
                vendor_products AS vp
            ON
                vp.product_id = pc.product_id
            WHERE
                pc.category_id = 2
            AND
                vp.vendor_id = 36
            AND 
                pc.subcategory_id IN (1,2)
            AND
                pc.subcategory_value_id IN (1,4)
```

And it returning me:

[image: It is returning duplicate entries]

I want those products only who fills all conditions of sub_category_value_id. Now it is returning all the conditions.

I am new to database and don't know much about queries.

Comment: The where clause looks ok, duplicates are probably caused by the joins. Try getting rid of those one at a time to test.

Comment: @OwlsSleeping That's the problem actually. I don't know how to do it.

Comment: You mention the relation output you are getting.  What is it that you expect to get that you aren't?  Is your only issue the duplicates you are seeing?

Comment: @KyleWilliamson Sorry, I post wrong question. I update it. Can u plz check it

Comment: Can you explain a bit more your problem ? I do not get the issue. Your filter on category & subcategory does not work ?

Comment: @LostReality subcategory_id(SCI) 1,2 are package & alcohol strength whereas subcategory_value_id(SCVI) 1&4 are pint & mild resp. I want all the pint and mild products. SCI-1 has pint(1), 500ml(2), quarter(3) and SCI-2 has mild(4) and strong(5). I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below query will give you distinct products with product_id and product_name on basis of given vendor_id, category_id, subcategory_id's and subcategory_value_id's.

Let me know if this works for you!

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT p.product_id,
p.product_name 
FROM products AS p
LEFT JOIN product_category AS pc ON p.product_id = pc.product_id
LEFT JOIN vendor_products AS vp ON p.product_id = vp.product_id
LEFT JOIN subcategories AS sc ON sc.subcategory_id = pc.subcategory_id
LEFT JOIN subcategories_value AS scv ON scv.subcategory_value_id = pc.subcategory_value_id
WHERE vp.vendor_id = 2 
    AND vp.category_id = 2 
    AND pc.subcategory_id IN (1, 2) 
    AND scv.subcategory_value_id IN (1, 4)
ORDER BY p.product_id;
```

Comment: @AkashRaut sounds great.. happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you shouldn't use left join to `product_category` table. The LEFT JOIN keyword returns all records from the left table (`product_category`) Please try like below:

```
SELECT
                p.product_id,
                p.product_name,
                p.product_photo,
                p.size,
                p.price,
                p.status,
                p.product_image_path
            FROM
                products AS p
            INNER JOIN
                product_category AS pc
            ON
                p.product_id = pc.product_id
            LEFT JOIN
                vendor_products AS vp
            ON
                vp.product_id = pc.product_id
            WHERE
                pc.category_id = 2
            AND
                vp.vendor_id = 36
            AND 
                pc.subcategory_id IN (1,2)
            AND
                pc.subcategory_value_id IN (1,4)
```

Comment: Isn't it the opposite ? LEFT JOIN returns all product even if there is no matching category.

Answer (score 0):

You want `group by` and `having`.  It is a little unclear what you mean by "all conditions", but it would look something like this:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM products p JOIN
     product_category pc
     ON p.product_id = pc.product_id JOIN
     vendor_products AS vp
     ON vp.product_id = pc.product_id
WHERE pc.category_id = 2 AND
      vp.vendor_id = 36 AND
      (pc.subcategory_id, pc.subcategory_value_id) IN ( (1, 1), (2, 4) )
GROUP BY p.product_id  -- this is okay because it is presumably the primary key
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT pc.subcategory_id) = 2;
```

Notes:

- The `WHERE` clause turns the `LEFT JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN`, so use the right `JOIN`.
- I assume you want pairs of values from the subcategory table.
- The `HAVING` clause insists on both subcatgories matching.

Comment: HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT pc.subcategory_id) = 2.... Can you plz explain me this query line ....?? The whole query is working for database but I want to add it as a PHP query to fetch data dynamically.

Comment: @AkashRaut . . . It is counting the number of matching subcategories and ensuring that both match.

Comment: Sorry to ask again but what should I declare for '2' in {pc.subcategory_id) = 2}. subcategory_id and subcategory_value_id is going to be change everytime i.e. it could be single value or multiple like earlier we have in query. HAVING COUNT is not returning the required output.